# FileOutputStream not working in Android

Tags: java, android, storage, internal, internal-storage

I'm using internal storage for the first time and my openFileOutput is giving me an error. I am not sure how to make this work, but the method below works perfectly fine if the FileOutputStream is removed. Thank you!

```
public void Addition(View view) {

    int num1 = numberone.getText().toString().trim().length();
    int num2 = numbertwo.getText().toString().trim().length();
    String numone = numberone.getText().toString();
    String numtwo = numbertwo.getText().toString();

    if(num1 == 0 || num2 == 0){
    TextView value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
    value.setText("Numbers not entered");
    }
    else if(numone.equals("+") || numtwo.equals("+") || numtwo.equals("-") || numone.equals("-")){
        TextView value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
        value.setText("Please enter numbers");
    }
    else{

answer = Float.parseFloat(numberone.getText().toString()) + Float.parseFloat(numbertwo.getText().toString());;

TextView value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);
value.setText("Your sum is " + answer);
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }

}
```

Comment: It does not recognize openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); It suggests I add a throw declaration or surround with try/catch. Thank you!

Comment: `openFileOutput` is a function of `ContextWrapper`. Where is this `Addition` function declared?

Comment: How would I use this correctly to store the float "answer"?

Comment: If it suggests you to surround the code with try/catch, then do so. Are you facing other problems?

Comment: Define 'does not recognize'. Insufficient information provided so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class doesn't extends a Context subclass, you need to pass a Context instance (an Activity, a Service, [etc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)) to call openFileInput.
Also you need to catch java.io.FileNotFoundException or add throws declaration to your method.

Hope it helps.